# My function does not take floats: - "TypeError('only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars')" (I think it has a quick fix!)

Tags: python, numpy, math, riemann

I wrote a code to use Riemann to calculate the area under certain function. It works well but when I set the boundaries to decimal number I get an error. I think I should tell the function I want to be able to enter floats but I don't see how. I  think it is an easy fix, hope someone can help me:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def func(x):
    return x ** 2

def func1(x):
    return x ** (x +0.5)

def func2(x):
    return np.sin(x)

def func3(x):
    return np.sin(x ** 2)

def riemann(f,a,b,N):
    dx = (b-a)/N
    x_midpoint = np.linspace(dx/2,b - dx/2,N)
    riemann_sum = np.sum(f(x_midpoint) * dx)
    return riemann_sum

res = riemann(func,0,1,10000)
res1 = riemann(func1,0,1,10000)
res2 = riemann(func2,0,1,10000)
res3 = riemann(func3,0,1,10000)


print("Midpoint Riemann Sum:",res)
print("Midpoint Riemann Sum:",res1)
print("Midpoint Riemann Sum:",res2)
print("Midpoint Riemann Sum:",res3)
```

Comment: Actually, it works for me. Can you post the case, where you are getting the error?

Comment: Make the code as small as possible, but still reproduce the error. Are all `func`-functions needed to reproduce the issue? Do you need to call `riemann` four times to reproduce the issue? Also, right now your code runs fine, I do not get any errors in Python 3.6

Comment: If a and b are for example 0.2 or 3.14 I get the error I stated in the title

Comment: Show the exact error with traceback

Comment: from the checking software: :S riemann works correct for a function below the x-axis.
  - "TypeError('only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars')" occured while trying to execute riemann(f=<function correctFunc3.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000001BA6DC94B70>, a=0, b=3.141592653589793, N=10000)

Comment: What's this `<function correctFunc3...>`?  I don't see anything like that in your code example.  Is this a generated function, say from `sympy`?  The fact that you import `math` makes me suspect you have a `func` that uses `math.sin(...)` which would produce this `size-1` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the followin output and no error found:

```
Midpoint Riemann Sum: 0.3333333325
Midpoint Riemann Sum: 0.527737838955
Midpoint Riemann Sum: 0.459697694323
Midpoint Riemann Sum: 0.310268301273
```

What can we do to reproduce the error ?

EDIT:

using a and b as decimals:

```
res = riemann(func,0.2,3.14,10000)
res1 = riemann(func1,0.2,3.14,10000)
res2 = riemann(func2,0.2,3.14,10000)
res3 = riemann(func3,0.2,3.14,10000)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Midpoint Riemann Sum: 9.66243875102
Midpoint Riemann Sum: 27.9239376537
Midpoint Riemann Sum: 1.87259837142
Midpoint Riemann Sum: 0.724064617658
```

and still got no error :/

Comment: If a and b are decimals, for example 0.2 or 3.14, I get the error I stated in the title

Comment: I am sorry I am so unclear, the check software gives this error. I think it has to do with that below the graph my area's are negative. in the syn(x) function for example, 0 to pi gives surface 0.45 but 0 to (2 * pi) gives 0, this should be 0.90. I think there is something wrong with my code in that sense